# Shopware 6 - how to add button component in the plugin System configuration in SW6

Tags: button, system-configuration, shopware6

I want to have button component or `input-type=button` on the plugin system configuration page.

Does anyone knows how to add it in `config.xml`

I went through main file of [Shopware Core System Config Schema](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shopware/platform/master/src/Core/System/SystemConfig/Schema/config.xsd) -

but `type` does not have any button related thing.

```
<xs:simpleType name="type">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="text"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="textarea"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="url"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="password"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="int"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="float"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="bool"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="checkbox"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="datetime"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="date"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="time"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="colorpicker"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="single-select"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="multi-select"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer:
You can spawn any vue-js component via the component type in your config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shopware/platform/master/src/Core/System/SystemConfig/Schema/config.xsd">
    <card>
        <title>#Test# Settings</title>

        <component name="sw-button">
            <name>button</name>
            <variant>primary</variant>
        </component>
    </card>
</config>
```

Every option you assign except for name is passed as a prop to the component.
However the problem with the sw-button is, that the text is given via the default slot which can not be passed as a prop. So unfortunately you can't create buttons via the config.xml

But this doenst really make sense anyway, since you cant control the actions that need to take place without any vue-js. The easiest thing would be to create your own vue-js module.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I found something relative to that.. if it gets worked i will post it or edit the que. .